# the script for disable hover from mobiles is open the link on self windows how i can fix that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem with a links on my website, when i tap on a link must be go to this link but i have to tap two times on a link then the link is open,
i fix that problem by using this jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
      var el = $(this);
      var link = el.attr('href');
      window.location = link;
   });
});
```

i have a button link when i click on it must be open a new tab but when i use this script the link is open on a **new tab and the self tab two**,

i don't want to open a link on a new and self tab, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
     var el = $(this);
      el.attr("target", "_blank");
      window.open(el.attr('href'));
   });
});
        </script>

</head>
<body>   
   <a rel="nofollow"  href="partnerwebsite.com" title="black cat print" class="spr buy-it-now">Buy it</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you @Vasim Vanzara but i don't have a new tab opan on all links on my website i have open new tab in a url in one button this and all links on the site work normally not open on new tab so i have a button with a class .buy-it to redirect this link onlly to partner site on new tab

Comment: i use this code the link open new tab on just the button i want but the hover effect is back again not disable this is new code any suggestion $(document).ready(function() {
   $('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
      var el = $(this);
      $('.buy-it-now').el.attr("target", "_blank");
      var link = el.attr('href');
      window.location = link;
   });
});

Comment: can you send you html

Comment: <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://partnerwebsite.com" title="black cat print" class="spr buy-it-now">Buy it</a>

Comment: my code in my question is working fine i just want to block the script to open all my internal links to open as a new tab except this button buy it

Comment: you can add condition if(el.attr('href') == "abc.com"){el.attr("target", "_blank");}else{el.attr("target", "");}

Comment: what that mean?  your code open a new tab on specific url abc.com but i have more than 3000 partner website so to not talking a long time i have a best solution to ignore hover effect on mobile devices

Comment: any one can help pleas This has its flaws. If you click a link with target="_blank" it will open in the same window AND in a new window.